# Верстка li элементов

Tags: вёрстка, css

У меня есть список ul с li элементами в которых находится фото разной высоты, но одинаковой  ширины. Как сделать, чтобы li были друг под другом без отступов сверху, снизу (случай когда разная высота img)?

Comment: напишите, что Вы сделали на данный момент

Comment: Вот что есть: http://jsfiddle.net/KUuFf/2/

Comment: для примеров используйте картинки с http://placehold.it/ например 

![](http://placehold.it/200x200)

Answer (score 1):

На бекграунд помести, чтобы высота картинки не влияла на высоту li

Comment: Можно пример?

Answer (score -1):

Вариант 1: Задай li фиксированную высоту, и пропиши ему overflow:hidden;
Вариант 2: Посчитай максимальную высотку картинки в скриптах, и задай её всем элементам.